# How to force web browser orientation in Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website, phaser-framework

I am trying to make a game like [Leonardo game](http://redcarpetrampage.com/).

But my problem is that my game has to play in landscape mode.

So I would like to force orientation on a mobile web browser.
(You will see [Leonardo game](http://redcarpetrampage.com/) that if playing the game in portrait mode, will rotate web browser to landscape.)

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to check out http://html5doctor.com/web-manifest-specification/

It looks like with modern browsers you can specify your desired orientation with this:

```
{
 "display": "fullscreen",
 "orientation": "landscape"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Open the game in browser chrome on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter B. said with JSON

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

manifest.json:

```
{
     "display":      "fullscreen", /* Could be "fullscreen", "standalone", "minimal-ui", or "browser" */
        "orientation":  "landscape", /* Could be "landscape" or "portrait" */
      }
```

But otherwise helpful for some stuff with JS.
How to determine if it's landscape or portrait:

```
 if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){}
```

And with webkit you could turn the page by 90° but I wouldn't really recommend that.